# How to document a method and specify its return type in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

How could I specify to the intellij the return type of a method?

```
/// <summary>
/// A method that returns a list of strings.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>List<String></returns>
private List<string> GetListOfStrings(){
   // Code...
   return list;
}
```

Notice that List is read just like a List in the intellij, how could I specify that's a list of strings?

Also, is there any site or tip/advice you can gimme about how to document in WPF?

Comment: `<see cref="List{T}" />`

Comment: @AndriyShevchenko It works! What does `see cref` stand for? Where I can find more things about this topic? Also feel free to put your reply as an answer to this post so I can put your answer as the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<see cref="List{T}" />` may work.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags) for C# documentation comments. It's available not only for WPF.

If you are looking for a good practices in XML documentation comments and good coding practices I'd suggest looking into a source code of a well-known libraries and frameworks.

For example [ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http/src/Builder/ApplicationBuilder.cs) source code or [WPF](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationCore/System/Windows/UIElement.cs) itself